# Select a tk radiobutton at startup

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

Python 3.4

I'm having what seems like a simple snag. I have a series of radiobuttons, choose one of many, and I just want to pick the first one as the default at startup, but after reading through the docs and a few how-to's I must be overlooking something.

It seems that invoke() or select() might do it, but I get "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invoke'", same for select. I also tried setting the state to 'selected' but that didn't seem to be a valid state for the radiobutton widget.

EDIT: My main concern was just how do I set a default button. The NoneType error isn't really my question. It's just the most recent error I ran into when experimenting. If I'd put less detail someone would complain "what have you tried?", etc.

I'm new to Python and Tk, so I guess I'm just overlooking something.

Example:

```
button1 = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text="Start", variable=m_type, value='start', command=start_options).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
button1.invoke()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have `grid()` on the same line.  It's returning a `NoneType` because the `grid()` method doesn't return anything.

I believe the `command` option specifies which function to run when the user clicks the button, so if that is what you are looking for, just let them click it.

```
button1 = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text="Start", variable=m_type, value='start',command=start_options)

button1.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
button1.invoke()
```

Comment: That was it. I knew it was just my novice skills holding me up with the syntax. I reformatted as you suggested and it worked the first time.